# Shell Script for merging multiple text files into One file fails

Tags: bash, shell

Need help in merging multiple text files in to one file,

When am doing this through shell script it is changing the alignment of the file.

**Eg : File 1 has data as below :**

```
Hello world
Hello World1
Hello World2
```

**File 2 has data as below :**

```
Hello New World
Hello New World 2
```

**Resultant file created through shell script post merging :**

```
Hello world Hello Wor
ld Hello world2
```

the lines of the files are clubbed together.

This shell script is executed on the AS400 system

Code used :

```
cat *.${3} >> ${2}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO, please do mention your expected output too in your post in code tags and do let us know. Kindly use CODE TAGS `{}` button while editing it too.

Comment: Hi @RavinderSingh13 Thank you .Sure the expected output is as follows :Hello world
Hello World1
Hello World2Hello New World
Hello New World 2

Comment: expected output is

Answer (score 1):

Try this..

`cat file1`

```
`Hello world
Hello World1
Hello World2`
```

`cat file1 >> file3`

`cat file3`

```
Hello world
Hello World1
Hello World2
```

`cat file2`

```
Hello New World
Hello New World 2
```

`cat file2 >> file3`

`cat file3`

```
Hello world
Hello World1
Hello World2
Hello New World
Hello New World 2
```

Another way out is :`$ sed -n wfile.merge file1.txt file2.txt`

Answer (score 0):

I will assume that :

1 - ${3} is the extension of the files you want to concatenate, and therefore *.${3} is the names of all the source files.

2 - The result you posted is not *actually* an exact output. (there is no "world2" word in the source files)

What comes to mind is that the line terminations of the source files might be causing the error. Perhaps some '\r' are present there ? You should check that the line endings are unix-style (lines end with '\n')

Otherwise, try running `cat File1` and `cat File2` and check that the output is as expected. This should give you a hint as to why they are catted wrong

Comment: Hi yes u are right $3 is the names of all the source file.. it is making the alignment change for all the lines in it

Comment: Hello world
Hello World1
Hello World2
Hello New World
Hello New World 2

Comment: So you say like the text files should have a end of line character

Comment: Thanks for your help